# Slow data insert on Sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I'm just trying to import data to database (Sql) from a dataset, but its a bit slower when I try to import 70000 rows. Am I doing something wrong or missing?
Could please give me some advice how can I do it better?

Here is my asp.net code:

```
ArtiDB entity = new ArtiDB();
int grid = 50;

foreach (string item_kisiler in kisiler)
{
    if (item_kisiler == "")
        continue;
    if (Tools.isNumber(item_kisiler) == false)
        continue;
    else
    {
        string gsm1 = item_kisiler;
        if (gsm1.Length > 10)
            gsm1 = gsm1.Substring(1, 10);
        entity.veriaktar(gsm1, gg, grid);

    }                       
}
```

This is my store prosedure:

```
alter proc veriaktar
(   
@gsm1 nvarchar(50)=null,   
@userid uniqueidentifier,
@grupid int = 0
)
as 
begin
Declare @AltMusID int
    if not exists (select * from tbl_AltMusteriler with (updlock, rowlock, holdlock) where Gsm1=@gsm1 and UserId=@userid)
        begin 
            insert into tbl_AltMusteriler (Gsm1,UserId) 
            values (@gsm1,@userid)          
            Set @AltMusID = scope_identity()
        end
    else
        begin 
        Set @AltMusID = (select AltMusteriID from tbl_AltMusteriler with (updlock, rowlock, holdlock) where Gsm1=@gsm1 and UserId=@userid)
        end
        if (@grupid != 0)
            begin
            if not exists (select * from tbl_KisiGrup with (updlock, rowlock, holdlock) where GrupID=@grupid and AltMusteriID=@AltMusID)
                begin
                    insert into tbl_KisiGrup values(@grupid,@AltMusID)
                end
            end
        end 

go
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do 70,000 individual inserts.  Where did the dataset get them from?

Comment: I just fill dataset from an excel sheet but it didnt take to much time...

Comment: The only "wrong" thing I'm seeing is you trying to insert so many lines at once. What about to split this into chunks or use a background service?

Comment: 70,000 individual inserts, considering the connection cost, transanction log cost, slow is expected. You should tune it into batch.

Comment: if I try to bulk insert how could I check if the data exists and how can I get identies?

Comment: Could you bulk into a temp/staging table then do a merge?

Answer (score 0):

The server is designed to work with sets.  You're requiring it to deal with one row at a time, and with each row *three* times.  Stop doing that and things will get better.

First go back to your VB docs and look for a way to do *one* `INSERT` for *all* 70,000 rows.  If you can use the Bulk Copy (bcp) feature of SQL Server, you should be able to insert the whole set in 10-20 seconds.

The read-test-update paradigm might work here, but it's error-prone and forces the server to work much harder than necessary.   If some of the 70,000 are new and others are updates, bulk them into a temporary table and use `MERGE` to apply it to `tbl_AltMusteriler`.

Second, `uniqueidentifier` isn't a good sign.  It looks like `tbl_AltMusteriler` is used to generate a surrogate key.  Why wouldn't a simple integer do?  It would be faster to generate (with `IDENTITY`), easier to read, faster to query, and have better PK properties generally.  (Also, make sure both the natural key and the surrogate are declared to be unique.  What would it mean if two rows have the same  values for `gsm1` and `userid`, differing only by `AltMusteriID`?)

In short, find a way to insert all rows at once, so that your interaction with the DBMS is limited to one or at most two calls.